# Simple Pagination in json reponse using Rails Rest routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, rest, pagination

I am building a simple service(API) that will return json reponse of users objects using Ruby on Rails. Since it returns an array of objects i want to add pagination functionality (:next_page , :prev) as follows.

```
"nextpage":www.domain.com/users?page=2&per_page=5
```

Currently i have a restful route that return url `www.domain.com/users`.How do i reconstruct the url in my index action and how do i make use of `limit` and `offset` in this case to make the pagination to work? I want to return 5 items in every page.Sorry i know it is a newbie question, it is my first time creating a service, if somebody could show me how to do the `nextpage` i would appreciate and i will implement `prev` by myself. I have tried looking for tutorials to do this but all of them they don't show the logic in the action/method.Thank you
**Note: I dont want to use will_paginate, i just need to build simple paginate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just append your page and page_per to your links to whatever action.  Assume you have standard restful resource based routing, i.e.

config/routes.rb:

```
resources :users
```

so you'd have the following route generated

GET '/users' => 'users#index'

if you send this url to your rails app:

'/users?page=2&per_page=5'

You will still get the index action,  but you'll have two extra parameters , you can do this:

controllers/users_controller.rb

```
def index
  if params[:page]
     # do your custom pagination
  else
     @users = User.all
  end
end
```